# What is the main concept for the turning mechanism on a n55 tricycle?

Tags: build, tricycle, framebuilding, steering, n55

I was looking at this spec sheet and all looks simple except how does the turning work.

https://www.n55.dk/MANUALS/SPACEFRAMEVEHICLES/spaceframevehicles.html

[XYZ ONESEATER construction plans](https://www.n55.dk/MANUALS/SPACEFRAMEVEHICLES/DIY.pdf)

Is there an academic text or book that explains the physics and build choices?

In general is the spec sheet in the link sufficient to build the trike?

I was assuming ball bearings would be involved in a turning mechanism but don't see their use.

From original article:

> Instead of using ball bearings for steering parts plastic washers can
> be used.

Comment: Welcome to to Bicycles SE. This may or may not fit within the scope of this exchange, but I will let some of the more seasoned members use their experience on that decision (they would likely direct you to another exchange if it did not).

Comment: requests for new tags typically happen over at the meta site

Comment: Tag created - it took a while to realise they don't make bikes in the common way.

Comment: Take a good look at the part that those two ball-tipped handles are attached to: It forms a rectangle where "self-greasing plastic washers" and "axial needle bearings" are used at the four corners. Those are the moving joints in the steering. The front wheels are attached to the short sides of the rectangle.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica that's an answer!

Comment: @Criggie Nah, it's neither an "academic text or book" and it does not "explain the physics and build choices". And I've not even checked whether the spec sheet is "sufficient to build the trike", though I have no doubt about that :-)

Comment: According to the drawing, you can use either or, not both.  I've added a snippet of the drawing to the Q.  Apparently all you need is a nut, bolt, and washers to create a steering mechanism.